# Einstein's summation convention with multiple terms

Tags: summation, matrix-equations, tensors, kronecker-delta

Let $$N_{ij} = \delta_{ij} - \epsilon_{ijk}n_k + n_in_j$$ and $$M_{ij}= \delta_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}n_k$$ where $n_i$ is the cartesian coordinates of the unit vector $\textbf{n}$.

Show that $$N_{ij}M_{jk}=2\delta_{ik}$$ Below is my working so far:

$N_{ij}M_{jk}=(\delta_{ij} - \epsilon_{ijl}n_l + n_in_j)(\delta_{jk} + \epsilon_{jkl}n_l)$  $\hspace{2em}$ [introducing new variable 'l']

=$\delta_{ik}-\epsilon_{ijl}\epsilon_{jkl}n_ln_l+\delta_{jk}n_in_j+\epsilon_{jkl}n_ln_in_j$

=$\delta_{ik}+2\delta_{ik}+\delta_{jk}n_in_j+\epsilon_{jkl}n_ln_in_j$

This is where I got stuck, since I am not familiar with the summation convention- especially with multiple terms.

NB - What should one do if an index appears more than twice in one term for Einstein convention?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aren't you missing two terms in the expansion?

Comment: @dm63 for the terms containing $\delta_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ multiplied together, I think the product is 0 (?) so I didn't put them down

Comment: that is only true if there are two indices in common (I,J in your example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $l$ only appears more than twice because you decide to "reuse" $l$ instead of using $m$ (say) in
$$
M_{jk}=\delta_{jk}+\epsilon_{jkl}n_l
$$
when you already used it in $N_{ij}$.

Moral of the story: don't ever reuse a symbol for suffix, or if you must (because you ran out of letters), add some decorations like primes, tildes or subscripts of suffix to distinguish them.

**Edit**

So you want to evaluate
$$
N_{ij}M_{jk}=(\delta_{ij}-\epsilon_{ijl}n_l+n_in_j)(\delta_{jk}+\epsilon_{jkm}n_m)
$$
Expanding the RHS,
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align*}
RHS&=(\delta_{ij}-\epsilon_{ijl}n_l+n_in_j)\delta_{jk}+(\delta_{ij}-\epsilon_{ijl}n_l+n_in_j)\epsilon_{jkm}n_m\\
&=\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}-\epsilon_{ijl}n_l\delta_{jk}+n_in_j\delta_{jk}+\delta_{ij}\epsilon_{jkm}n_m-\epsilon_{ijl}n_l\epsilon_{jkm}n_m+n_in_j\epsilon_{jkm}n_m\\
&=\delta_{ik}-\cancel{\epsilon_{ikl}n_l}+n_in_k+\cancel{\epsilon_{ikm}n_m}-\epsilon_{ijl}n_l\epsilon_{jkm}n_m+n_in_j\epsilon_{jkm}n_m
\end{align*}
$$
Note that $\epsilon_{jkm}$ is antisymmetric in $j,m$ but $n_mn_in_j$ is symmetric in $j,m$, so their contraction is gives 0.  Also, recall the contraction of two $\epsilon$'s:
$$
\epsilon_{ijl}\epsilon_{jkm}=\epsilon_{jli}\epsilon_{jkm}=\delta_{lk}\delta_{im}-\delta_{lm}\delta_{ik}
$$
So this gives
$$
\begin{align*}
RHS&=\delta_{ik}+n_in_k-(\delta_{lk}\delta_{im}-\delta_{lm}\delta_{ik})n_ln_m\\
&=\delta_{ik}+\cancel{n_in_k}-\cancel{n_kn_i}+\delta_{ik}\underbrace{n_mn_m}_{=\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{n}=1}\\
&=2\delta_{ik}
\end{align*}
$$

Of course, without using summation convention, you could approach it as: 
$N$ represents $\mathbf{x}\mapsto\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n}+\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x})$ and $M$ represents $\mathbf{x}\mapsto\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n}$, so the composition is
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}&\mapsto(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n})-(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n})\times\mathbf{n}+\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n}))\\
&=(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n})-(\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n}-(\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{n})\mathbf{x}+(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{n})\mathbf{n})+\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x})\\
&=2\mathbf{x}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: @ user10354138 Thank you for the response, but even if I do replace the $l$ in $M_{jk}$ to $m$, I am still struggling to get to the answer of $2\delta_{ik}$. Please can you elaborate on your answer.

Comment: I've added the full computation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think of getting rid of the Kronecker delta in each term this way.